# EF core 3.1 HasQueryFilter with Load

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have class `Cycle` that contains list of `employees`. `Employee` has `User` property that is reference to User and user has property `IsDeleted` because we use soft delete. We use `HasQueryFilter(e => !e.IsDeleted)` to prevent getting deleted user. With `Include` this works perfectly, but because of performance issues in EF 3.1 we started using `Load`. Everything is much faster but `HasQueryFilter` is not applied and I get `Employee` with `User` that is null. Is `HasQueryFilter` not applicable with `load`?

```
public class Employee
{
     ...
     public ICollection<CycleEmployee> Employees { get; protected set; } = new List<CycleEmployee>();
}

public class CycleEmployee
{
    public User User { get; protected set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; protected set; }
}
```

And in `CycleEmployee` I get `UserId` always, but `User` prop is null if User is soft deleted

Fetching data with load:

```
public Cycle GetCycle(Guid cycleId, params string[] includeProperties)
    {
        var query = DbContext
            .Cycles
            .Where(e => e.OrganizationId == CurrentUser.OrganizationId);
        var cycle = query.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == cycleId);
        query.LoadMultipleProperties(includeProperties);

        return cycle;
    }

public static void LoadMultipleProperties<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, params string[] includeProperties)
        where T : class
    {
        foreach (var prop in includeProperties)
        {
            query.Include(prop).Load();
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

When using include: List of employees is empty(because User inside Employee is soft deleted) - expected result

When using load: List of employees is not empty(I get Employee entities where User is null but UserId is not null) - problem

Comment: What do you mean by *"With `Include` this works perfectly"*? What's the difference when you use `Include` directly vs `query.Include().Load()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has similar problem follow [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23510) link. In short, you have to apply filter for inner entities as well.